# Does `cin` produce a newline automatically?

Tags: c++

Let's consider the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"First-";
    std::cout <<"-Second:";
    int i;
    std::cin>>i;
    std::cout<<"Third in a new line.";

    while(1){}


}
```

The output when value 4 is given to `i` is:

```
First--Second:4
Third in a newline
```

`cout` doesn't print any newline. But after I input any value(4) for `i` a newline is printed. There could be two possible reasons for this:

> - The Enter key I press after typing a numerical value for `i` is printed as a newline.
> - `cin` automatically generates a newline.

Although the first reason seems more reasonable but the reason, I am thinking 2nd reason could also be true, is because after `Third` is printed when I press `Enter` no new line is printed even the program continue to run because of `while(1)`--which means the console window doesn't print a newline when `Enter` key is pressed. So it seems like `cin` automatically prints a newline.

So, why is the newline being generated after I give input to `cin`? Does `cin` automatically prints a newline?

Comment: This is a **good question**. You've tried to figure the problem out yourself, and have created and tested various hypotheses. I wish more people would do that. However, this isn't really about software engineering concepts, so it's not a good fit for Programmers. I've voted to migrate to Stack Overflow, which is a better fit for implementation questions.

Comment: @amon Thanks for your response. Actually I was double minded before asking the question -- program.se or stackoverflow? I thought things might go conceptutal as _this is how `cin` works in c++.. ...there are xyz reasons why cin is defined this way..._. If it is more appropriate at stackoverflow then please migrate it.

Comment: You should observe that `4` appears when you press the `4` key, and the newline appears when you press the Enter key

Comment: @M.M Why doesn't the newline appear for subsequent Enter hits?

Comment: There was no input happening at that time; if you replace your infinite loop with a timed pause and then an input, you'd see all the other keystrokes at that time

Answer (score 6):

The number and newline you entered is printed **by the console software**. `cin` won't print anything in my understanding.

Try giving some input via redirect or pipe, and I guess you will see no new line printed.
For example:

```
$ echo 4 | ./a.out
First--Second:Third in a new line.
```

where `$` is the prompt and `echo 4 | ./a.out(Enter)` is your input.

Comment: I don't know about _prompt, redirect_ and _pipe_. But thanks for the answer. I'll study them soon.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out: http://ideone.com/tBj1uS

You can see there that input and output are separated.

`stdin`:

```
1
2
```

`stdout`:

```
First--Second:Third in a new line.
```

Which means, that the newline is produced by the Enter key and is a part of the input, not the output.

Comment: That IDE is weird. It doesn't ask for _input!!_.

Comment: It's an online IDE. There is no console. You type your input *beforehand*. See the `stdin` part.

Answer (score 1):

If someone will have the same problem, I was able to solve it like this:

```
string ans1;
getline(cin, ans1);
    ans1.erase(remove(ans1.begin(), ans1.end(), '\n'),
        ans1.end());
int ans1int = atoi(ans1.c_str());
```

Basically, it works by deleting all the newline characters in the string, and then ,aking it integer or whatever else you need. Also you will need **algorithm** library for it
It's not that elegant, but hey, it works!